# Where did 100GB go?

Tags: linux, disk-space

I have Ubuntu installed on my laptop.

`cfdisk` shows 150GB hard disk which is correct.

`Baobab` shows 56GB only.

Also, wherever I try to download something using `Transmission` torrent client it complains that disk space is not sufficient.

There is nothing on my disk except a few movies.

Where is all the space?

Comment: What does `df -h` say?

Answer (score 2):

You could try `$ sudo du -sh /*` to get an overview of everything taking up space on your drive. It sounds like you might have partitioned your drive down to a 56GB volume, even if you don't have the other 94GB allocated to a different partition.

Comment: I tried this command it says `117G /home` but I don't have 117G files anywhere. How do I join that 94GB to this 56G if that is the case?

Comment: Thank you very much for this command. I've been searching for this before.

Comment: @TheMachine: Go deeper in the search and run `sudo du -sh /home/*` to see more detailed info from that folder.

Answer (score 2):

You can use utilities such as [KDirStat](http://kdirstat.sourceforge.net/) to visualize where your free space went.

[image]

[WinDirStat](http://windirstat.info/) and [Disk Inventory X](http://www.derlien.com/) are similar tools for Windows and Mac OS X, respectively.

Comment: And Baobab is the GNOME equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure in installation that Ubuntu was set to use the whole disk and not a portion if it?

Check out your partitions by using `gparted` (`sudo apt-get install gparted`). Be **very** careful though. As noted elsewhere, `gparted` is a weapon of mass destruction.