# Hard Drive missing drive space

Tags: hard-drive, disk-space

I have a 500 GB hard drive which I previously attached to my Mac.  I detached the drive without going through the eject procedure.  When I did this a message showed up, which of course I did not read.  I could not use the drive until I formatted again.  Now, when I attach the drive it says it is formatted NTFS and has 280.39 of 500 GB free.  When I open the drive in Windows Explorer, Finder, or in Linux, is only shows a handful of files totaling 54 MB.  How can I find out what is taking up all the space.

**Edit:** Output of `fdisk -l`:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 68.7 GB, 68719476736 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 8354 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00031a5e

Device Boot Start End Blocks Id System
/dev/sda1 * 1 8068 64804864 83 Linux
/dev/sda2 8069 8355 2300929 5 Extended
/dev/sda5 8069 8355 2300928 82 Linux swap / Solaris


Disk /dev/sdb: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x288d48f2

Device Boot Start End Blocks Id System
/dev/sdb1 1 60802 488383488 7 HPFS/NTFS
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://superuser.com/q/227055/4782

Comment: Please attach it to a Linux machine, and add the output of `sudo fdisk -l` to your question. Thanks.

Comment: Disk /dev/sda: 68.7 GB, 68719476736 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 8354 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00031a5e

Comment: Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1        8068    64804864   83  Linux
/dev/sda2            8069        8355     2300929    5  Extended
/dev/sda5            8069        8355     2300928   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Comment: Disk /dev/sdb: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x288d48f2

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1               1       60802   488383488    7  HPFS/NTFS

Comment: Would you kindly edit that output into your question, so that it becomes readable?

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, use Disk Manager.  In Linux, use something like fdisk or Gpartd. I think you may have a partition taking up space.

Comment: I'm not so sure of that. He said Explorer says 280.39 of 500. If it was another partition it would only show the size of the partition, not the size of the drive.

Comment: He should check for hidden files then. Probably dot files (files starting with a .).  If the original author is using Windows, then the Folder Option to view hidden files will need to be turned on.  Under Linux, use ls -la in a terminal window (actually the same for the Mac as well if I recall correctly).

Answer (score 0):

On OSX, *BSD or Linux

> cd /Volumes/NAME_OF_DISK
>   du -a  | sort -nrk1 | more

You will see all files on the volume (including ones that begin with .) sorted from the largest to smallest.  The "." and ".." entries in this mode are misleading as they represent the current working directory and the parent.  Ignore them.

df -h will show you the mounts in 'human readable format'